# Neovim - how to make command :below terminal to work the same as in regular Vim?

Tags: vim, terminal, neovim

When I run command **:below terminal** in Neovim it opens a new tab with terminal from where I cannot jump back to the code. How to make in Neovim the same behaviour as in the regular Vim for the command **:below terminal** when the normal/regular terminal opens under the code?
I know there is a command in Neovim like **:split +term** but then a very strange terminal opens where you need to switch into the insert mode to start typing - it is just not as good terminal as in the regular Vim.

Answer (score 0):

In Neovim if you put this in your `init.vim` file:

```
autocmd TermOpen * startinsert
```

then `:split +term` will behave nearly identically to Vim's `:below terminal`, including not having to explicitly switch to insert mode